# Wrapper WebAPI vs IIS Url Rewrite

Tags: c#, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-web-api2, wrapper

Dears,

I am going to make an integration with another, let's say **'system X to out system Y'** but there are some limitations
System X will not access servers directly, so will create a wrapper API to be accessible for System X.

**Wrapper API Role**
Nothing more than the below,

1. System X call Wrapper API
2. Wrapper API call System Y
3. System Y respond to Wrapper API
4. Wrapper API respond to System X

Simply will work as a router, route requests from System X to System Y.

So i am thinking to use IIS URL Rewrite instead.

**My question here**, Is IIS URL Rewrite will be enough for this case or i will facing some problems
noting that all HTTP verbs will be used?

***Thanks in advance***

Answer (score 0):

When URL rewrite works as a reverse proxy with ARR , it just route the request to system Y without  making any change to the request context. So if you your system Y require extra request or authentication header. It will probably fail.

Of course, if your wrapper WEB API just works as a normal reverse proxy and it didn't make any change in request body. Then you could try to use URL rewrite instead.